# TYPO3 form - Bootstrap styling of checkboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Is there a ready to use css snippet to style the checkboxes created with TYPO3 extension form (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/8.7/)? The html of the form checkbox element looks like this:

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input checkbox">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="add-on form-check-label" for="basicContactForm-checkbox-1">
            <input name="tx_form_formframework[BasicContactForm][checkbox-1]" value="" type="hidden">
            <input required="required" class="add-on" id="basicContactForm-checkbox-1" name="tx_form_formframework[BasicContactForm][checkbox-1]" value="1" type="checkbox">
            <span>Yes, I confirm!<span class="required">*</span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to style it sth similar like e.g. Awesome Bootstrap Checkbox:

https://www.cssscript.com/demo/pretty-checkbox-radio-inputs-with-bootstrap-and-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox-css/

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this will work

added a span to your html- see the note below
the rest is just css - I hope this helps you out

if you cant add any html and it has to be straight css then this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jr4h1ek/) will work(best i can do on the fly). expanding on this css should do the trick

```css
.form-check {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.form-check input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #e3e4e5;
}

.form-check input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: purple;
}

.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.form-check input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

.form-check .checkmark:after {
    left: 7px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input checkbox">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="add-on form-check-label" for="basicContactForm-checkbox-1">
            <input name="tx_form_formframework[BasicContactForm][checkbox-1]" value="" type="hidden">
            <input required="required" class="add-on" id="basicContactForm-checkbox-1" name="tx_form_formframework[BasicContactForm][checkbox-1]" value="1" type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span><!-- added for checkbox -->
            <span>Yes, I confirm!<span class="required">*</span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I can add <span class="checkmark"> ... need to figure it out first. Is there another workaround?

Comment: why you do not just follow the repository docs  https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox like i described below?

Comment: see my updated answer - i added in a jsfiddle that could help you out

Comment: Did you try to override the Checkbox partial? See the docs https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/FAQ/Index.html#how-do-i-override-the-frontend-templates. The partial is located here: .\typo3\sysext\form\Resources\Private\Frontend\Partials\Checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS to your head and follow the Docs on github https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox

Comment: ... it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/hfLhv8hq/ .... I can't change the html structure ... it's auto generated